# Android RecyclerView is giving exception in rendering in XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

Please help!
I am using RecyclerView for first time and having problem during rendering,
I haven't done any java code because I got this error,

> Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
>   - android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Open Class, Show Exception)  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show
>   sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Service:
>   accessibility   at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext.getSystemService(BridgeContext.java:463)
>   Copy stack to clipboard

This is my xml code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

how do I solve this problem? I have searched on the internet but could not find right solution...

Comment: I have added in my gradle.build file:  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
but there is still same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View.isInEditMode() is used to skip code which is not executable in preview mode of Custom View we create. It may happen you are using older version of RecyclerView library which had no preview in Design Mode of Android.

try to update your recyclerview library and problem will be solved.here is what current version as of now replace it in your gradle.build file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
```

Comment: I already have added above dependency to my gradle .build file it is not solving the problem,

but updating library may work but how do I update it for RecyclerView?

Comment: new version of recyclerview does not have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

2 suggestions :

1. upgrade your sdk to 22
2. set layout for recyclerview if you are not setting,

eg : `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`

in most of the case sdk version is the problem, so try updating your sdk first